# Duplicate Order for one payment through Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express, order-duplication

Duplicate order on **Magento v 1.9.1.0.**, triggered by:

**PayPal API error code 10486**

In short, the site responds to this error appropriately and as said in the doc: when the buyer's first payment is denied, the buyer is redirected back to PayPal.

(PayPal has confirmed this behavior, and told me to contact the developers in charge of this extension to report on this issue).

The problem seems to be linked to that redirection, which creates two orders in Magento (the two payment attempts — the first being denied by PayPal — are interpreted as two different orders/invoices. The buyer is charged once.).

Thus, in the backend (Sales > Orders) we can see for the same transactionid (PayPal) :

- 2 different order ID numbers (magento)
- 2 different correlationid
- a «  Completed » vs. « completed » payer address status (different syntax)
- an « IPN "Completed" » comment noticed on the first order

What could be done to solve this?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Hi , did you ever get the solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a bug and should be fixed (we get this occasionally). But the workaround we use, which does not appear to break anything, at least in our case, is:

- **Look at** each of the orders, especially the invoices tab
- **Accept** the order with the correct invoice amount (in our case it has always been the one with higher increment_id)
- **Delete** the incorrectly sized invoice directly from database (tables sales_flat_invoice and sales_flat_invoice_grid)
- **Delete** the order directly from database (tables sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_grid)
- **Manually verify** the stock status of the products included in the order

Comment: I just had this happen in a Magento installation I am working on.  The order repeated 6 times.  Is deleting the only way?  Or can I cancel the first orders instead?

Comment: You can't cancel the orders through the admin interface (unless you have an extension that lets you cancel invoiced orders). And you shouldn't refund the orders, since this messes up the accounting (might not be an issue in your case, but with us it is). Deleting the orders from database is the only way that restores accounting integrity.

Comment: Only the last order has been invoiced.  The other ones aren't invoiced.  Should I just cancel them?

Comment: Oh, this must be a different issue then. In our case all (or both) orders appear invoiced, so they can't be cancelled. I think you could try to cancel the orders, but be prepared to manually delete them from the database in case it does not work.